# Why is my flask application following the error route?

Tags: python, html, flask

I am trying to write a code (CS50) that uses flask and HTML and I am supposed to create a server where you can input your name as well as a provided option. After this, the results are displayed in a table, the file is called registration.html, (using HTML) as well as recorded in a SQL database.

This is the code for app.py

```
from cs50 import SQL
from flask import Flask, redirect, render_template, request

app = Flask(__name__)
db = SQL("sqlite:///froshims4.db")
OPTIONS = [ "Stochastic Calculus",
            "Financial Engineering",
            "Statistical Sciences",
            "Algorithmic Progression Systems",
            "Econometrics"]

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("index.html", options=OPTIONS)
@app.route("/register",methods=['POST'])
def register():
    name = request.form.get("name")
    option = request.form.get("option")
    if not name or option not in OPTIONS:
        return render_template("error.html")
    db.execute("INSERT INTO registrants (name,option) VALUES (?,?)",name,option)

    return redirect ('/registrants')
#Flask includes a redirect function which redirects to another route.
@app.route("/registrants")
def registrants():
    registrants = db.execute("SELECT * from registrants ")
    return render_template("registrants.html", registrants=registrants)
```

This is the code for index:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block body %}

    <h1>Register</h1>
    <form action="/register" method="post">
        #we plan to create a register route
        <input autocomplete="off" autofocus name="name" placeholder="Name" type="text">
<!--a select menu is sort of like a drop down menu <select name="sport"> <option disable selected>Sport</option> -->
<!-- A radiobutton is mutually exclusive checkbox where the user can sign up for only one option-->
            {% for option in options %}
                 <input name="option" type="checkbox" value="'{{option}}">{{option}}
            {% endfor %}
        </select>
        <input type="submit" value="Register">
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

app.py directs me to error.html even if I have entered a name and a feasible option. Why is this? How can I fix it? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

```
<input name="option" type="checkbox" value="'{{option}}">{{option}}
```

You have an extra single-quote inside `value=`. So the actual value being returned is e.g. `'Stochastic Calculus` which does not match any value in the `OPTIONS` list.

Also you don't have a closing `</option>` tag.